# Swiper, табы, инициализация нескольких слайдеров

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется несколько слайдеров swiper, и табы для переключения на соответствующий слайдер.
Активным должен быть только один слайдер, остальные должны быть скрыты.
Подскажите, как правильно сделать переключение слайдера, т.е. когда происходит клик по табу, нужно текущий слайдер остановить, а новый инициализировать.
т.е. при загрузке страницы не хотелось-бы инициализировать сразу все слайдеры, т.к. их может быть много.
А также вопрос по resize также интересует, как правильно делать реинициализацию при изменении размера экрана?
для мобилок нужно к примеру добавлять элементы в слайд, перестраивать разметку.
https://jsfiddle.net/vsfpr7b5/
ссылка на страницу плагина http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
  // Optional parameters
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 2,

  autoplay: {
   delay: 2500,
   disableOnInteraction: true,
  },

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
   el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
   nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
   prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
   el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
 })

    $('.tab').on('click', function(e){

    })
```

```css
.main{
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        li{
            display: inline-block;
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        .swiper-slide{
            margin: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.js"></script>
    
<div class="main">
    <div class="main__tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab">tab1</li>
            <li class="tab">tab2</li>
            <li class="tab">tab3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main__slider">
        <div class="main_slider1 slider">
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_slider2 slider">
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_slider3 slider">
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: есть идеи как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Решение может быть таким:

```css
#myTabContent{
        background-color:#fefefe;
        padding:15px;
    }
    .main{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .swiper-slide{
        background-color:#ddd;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .swiper-text .swiper-slide{
        background-color:#ddd;
        padding: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html dir="ltr" lang="ru">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
   
<div class="main">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="slider1-tab" href="#slider1">First</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="slider2-tab" href="#slider2">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="slider3-tab" href="#slider3">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane show active" id="slider1">
            <div class="swiper-container" id="slider1_1">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper swiper-text">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1 - 1 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2 - 1 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3 - 1 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4 - 1 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5 - 1 slider</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="slider2" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="swiper-container" id="slider2_1">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
              <div class="swiper-container" id="slider2_2">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper swiper-text">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1 - 2 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2 - 2 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3 - 2 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4 - 2 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5 - 2 slider</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="slider3" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="swiper-container" id="slider3_1">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper swiper-text">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1 - 3 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2 - 3 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3 - 3 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4 - 3 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5 - 3 slider</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var mySwipers = {};

function initSwiper(id,idname){ 
   
   var allslider = $(id).find('.swiper-container');
   
   $.each(allslider,function(key,val){
    var selecto = id +' #'+$(val).attr('id');
      mySwipers[idname] = new Swiper (selecto, {
          // Optional parameters
          loop: key == 0 ? true : false,
          slidesPerView: 4,
          slidesPerGroup:1,
          autoplay: {
            delay: key == 0 ? 1500 : 1000,
            disableOnInteraction: false
          },
          spaceBetween:15,
          pagination: {
            el: selecto+' .swiper-pagination',
            dynamicBullets:true,
            dynamicMainBullets:3
          },
          navigation: {
            nextEl: selecto+' .swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: selecto+' .swiper-button-prev',
          },
          on:{
            slideChange(){
                //console.log('change slide ',this.activeIndex , this.el.id);
            }
          },
            breakpoints: {
                320: {
                  slidesPerView: 1,
                  spaceBetween: 10
                },
                768: {
                  slidesPerView: 2,
                  spaceBetween: 15
                },
                1024: {
                  slidesPerView: 3,
                  spaceBetween: 15
                }
              },
            observer:true,
            observeParents:true,
            observeSlideChildren:true
        })
        
    })
    
}

    $('#myTab a').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
          
        var self = this;
        var id = $(e.target).attr('href');

        var re = /#/gi;
        var idname = id.replace(re, '');
          
        $(self).tab('show');
        initSwiper(id,idname);
       
    })

    
     initSwiper('#slider1','slider1');
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Подключены точки останова для адаптивности, слайдер чувствителен к изменению размеров.
Если снять комментарий в функции смены слайдов `slideChange`, то в консоли вы можете увидеть, что активные действия исходят только от слайдеров, которые находятся в активной вкладке, остальные останавливаются.